# PHP, MYSQL,JSOn Fast search functionality tips for social networking website

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi I am developing social networking website and need a suggestion. I am using codeignitor framework, php as core language and jQuery as client side script.

Now I want to implement user search functionality to the website where a user can search for another users.

If I am using pagination with php it is bit slow and performance is not fast and even if the database will be huge then it will be more slow.

so what I have tried is, I made query of first 1000 people and encoded with json and showing first 10 results at a time by using this plugin http://www.stephenrhoades.com/?p=8

Is there anyone who can help my what all thing I need to follow here including technology, tips, query, mysql database etc.

Here is my current function in model

```
    function search_user($cntry,$male,$female,$age_min,$age_max){

               $this->db->select('user_profiles.user_id,user_profiles.first_name,
               user_profiles.birthday,user_profiles.gender,user_profiles.picture,
               user_profiles.last_active,location.city,location.country');

     $this->db->from('user_profiles');

     $this->db->join('location', 'user_profiles.user_id = location.user_id');

     $this->db->limit(800);


    // Search condition :::: Country 

    if($cntry){
    $this->db->like('location.country',$cntry, 'both');
    }

    // Search condition :::: Male or Female 

     if($male==1 && $female==0) {  $g='Male'; $this->db->like('user_profiles.gender',$g, 'both');  }

     if($male==0 && $female==1) {  $g='Female'; $this->db->like('user_profiles.gender',$g, 'both');  }

     // Search condition :::: Age range
     if($age_min && !$age_max){

        $this->db->where('(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(user_profiles.birthday)) >= ', $age_min);
     }


     if($age_min && $age_max){

        $this->db->where('(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(user_profiles.birthday)) >= ', $age_min); 
        $this->db->where('(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(user_profiles.birthday)) <= ', $age_max); 
     }


     $this->db->order_by("user_profiles.last_active", "desc"); 
     $query = $this->db->get();


     $data=array();
     foreach ($query->result() as $row){     
     $row->last_active=$this->online_status($row->last_active);
     $row->birthday=$this->birthday($row->birthday);
     $data[]=$row;
     }


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $data;
    }
    else
    {
    $data = array(
                'result' =>'404'
                 );
    return $data; 
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: requires the inclusion of a minimum number of characters and places a limit to the query!

Comment: If I will limit the query using this plugin for example 50 it will not show more results then 50 as search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous factors that could lead to this process being slow. These are questions that we'd need to address:

- What columns are you searching in your database?
- Are those columns indexed?
- What does your query look like? Are you only returning necessary columns?
- How quickly do you want to show results? Immediately as user types, or after they click 'search'?
- How do you return results?
- How do you display results?

Generally, you can search VERY large datasets in a matter of milliseconds - so I doubt the database is the issue as long as you have things set up correctly.

**OK, with all that being said...**

If you do have a VERY large social network, I would recommend implementing something like [Zend Search Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html). It's a search index and can be implemented into CodeIgniter pretty easily:

http://www.cmjackson.net/2009/02/17/how-to-use-zend_search_lucene-with-the-php-framework-codeigniter/

You can add your users, their profile data, posts, comments, etc. into the index and search it with a powerful language processing query language, and return results very quickly and in any format you wish. This is very easy to turn into a "live" search with ajax and json.

Comment: Hi Swatkins, Thanks to answer my question. These tips are really helpful for me. Here are answers of your questions... I am searching user_id, username, first_name, picture, birthday, gender and online_status. And, no my table is not indexed I am only using user_id as primary key. I am returning only specified columns.I want search reselt immediately once user land to page and then onclick and onchange inputs. I need output results to diplay profile and basic info of users.

Comment: Can you offer your query? Are you using mysql?

Comment: I edit the query in my main question. And here is live website where you can track performance if you have time I will appreciate http://meetm8.com User: demo@demo.com and Pass: 12345

Comment: Could you turn on profiling - $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); in the controller

Comment: OK, sorry for the delay. I've just taken a look at your pages.  I don't think there is much of a problem here. Your jquery plugin uses the results from the search at http://meetm8.com/search/search_user to paginate the results (this is really fast - so no problem there). I think your query is pretty good, though I'd probably optimize a little bit there (using `like` for Male/Female seems like overkill). Anyway, with just a few options for search capabilities, I think you'd be better off caching the json results to a file and returning the contents of those files based on the user's choices.

Comment: (continued comment) - So, the first time someone searches for All Countries, Male, 18 - 34 - you could take those results and write a file with the json contents called 'All_countries.male.18.34.json'. And in your search_user method, check for the existence of that file and return it if it exists, and query the database if it doesn't (then create the new file from the queried results).  Of course, you'd want to refresh that cache at some interval, but that would be up to your network and how frequently the user list changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot swatkins.... your advice is really helpful for me.. Thanks again for your time.... indeed..